# Why does my compiler use an 8-bit char when I'm running on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, byte, bit

I am using the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 IDE**. When I compile a program in C++ while using the header **`<climits>`**, I output the macro constant **`CHAR_BIT`** to the screen. It tells me there are *8-bits* in my char data type (which is 1-byte in C++). However, Visual Studio is a *32-bit* application and I am running it on a *64-bit* machine (i.e. a machine whose processor has a 64-bit instruction set and operating system is 64-bit Windows 7).

I don't understand why my char data type uses only 8-bits. Shouldn't it be using at least 32-bits (since my IDE is a 32-bit application), let alone 64-bits (since I'm compiling on a 64-bit machine)?

I am told that the number of bits used in a memory address (1-byte) depends on the hardware and implementation. If that's the case, why does my memory address still only use 8-bits and not more?

Comment: Besides being the canonical byte size, if Microsoft ever changed that, everything would break.

Comment: The addressable unit on x64 is still an octet. Making char wider "because it's allowed" would just be a giant waste of space.

Comment: You might want to read up on `wchar_t`, and, because this is MSVC, `TCHAR`

Comment: *"the number of bits used in a memory address (1-byte)"*  This is not true.  On your 64-bit machine, every one of your 8-bit bytes has a 64-bit address identifying its "location".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are confusing memory **address** bit-width with data **value** bit-width. Memory addresses (pointers) are 32 bits for 32-bit programs and 64 bits for 64-bit programs. But data types have different widths for their values depending on type (as governed by the standard). So a char is 8-bits, but a char* will be 32-bits if you are compiling as a 32-bit application (also note here it depends on how you compile the application and not what type of processor or OS you are running on).

Edit for questions:

*However, what is the relationship between these two?*

Memory addresses will always have the same bit width regardless of what data value is stored there.

*For example, if I have a 32-bit address and I assign an 8-bit value to that address, does that mean there are 24-bits of unused address space?*

Some code (assume 32-bit compilation):

```
char i_am_1_byte = 0x00;         // an 8-bit data value that lives in memory
char* i_am_a_ptr = &i_am_1_byte; // pointer is 32-bits and points to an 8-bit data value

*i_am_a_ptr = 0xFF; // writes 0xFF to the location pointed to by the pointer
                    // that is, to i_am_1_byte
```

So we have `i_am_1_byte` which is a char and takes up 8 bits *somewhere* in memory. We can get this memory location using the address-of operator `&` and store it in the pointer variable `i_am_a_ptr`, which is your 32-bit address. We can write 8 bits of data to the location pointed to be `i_am_a_ptr` by dereferencing it.

*If not, what is the bit-width for memory address actually used for*

All the data that your program uses must be located somewhere in memory and each location has an address. Most programs probably will not use most of the memory available for them to use, but we need a way to address every possible location.

*how can having more memory address bit-width be helpful?*

That depends on how much data you need to work with. A 32-bit program, at most, can address 4GB of memory space (and this may be smaller depending on your OS). That used to be a very, very large amount of memory, but these days it is conceivable a program could run out. It is also a lot easier for the CPU to address more the 4GB of RAM if it is 64-bit (this gets into the difference between physical memory and virtual memory). Of course, 64-bit architecture means a lot more than just bigger addresses and brings many benefits that may be more useful to programs than the bigger memory space.

Comment: That is a very good explanation and yes I was confusing address bit-width with data value bit-width. However, what is the relationship between these two? For example, if I have a 32-bit address and I assign an 8-bit value to that address, does that mean there are 24-bits of unused address space? If not, what is the bit-width for memory address actually used for and how can having more memory address bit-width be helpful?

Comment: @WanderingIdiot it seems as though you are still confusing bytes with their addresses.  You don't assign an 8-bit value to an *address*, you assign it to *where that address points*.  It's like houses and house numbers.  The size of one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: @plasmoidia thank you for the edit. From your clear explanation I completely understand now. To sum up what I learned from your detailed answer above, having a 32-bit address allows you access to 2^32 or 4,294,967,296 bytes = 4 GB of memory, and having a 64-bit address allows you access to 2^64 or 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 bytes = 17,179,869,184 GB or 16 EB (exabytes) of memory. From those figures, it doesn't seem like we will have an issue with memory limitations for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting fact is that on some processors, such as 32-bit ARM, mostly of their instructions are word aligned. That is, compilers tend to allocate 32-bits (4 bytes) to any data type, even though the data type used needs less than 4 bytes unless otherwise stated in the source code. This happens because ARM architectures are optimized to memory access using word alignment.

Comment: The 32-bit ARM processors fetch data in either 8-bit units or 32-bit units.  Usually, the processor always fetches 32 bits of data and ignores 24 bits in the case of 8-bit fetches.